# Can I upload an article to arxiv AFTER it was accepted to IEEE?

Tags: publications, arxiv, ieee

I found that pre-prints are somehow allowed to publish on arxiv, before they are reviewed by IEEE.

What about **after** the paper is published in a conference?
Can I upload it to arxiv?

And if so, in what terms?

Comment: Ask the editor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [IEEE post-publication policy](https://conferences.ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/author-ethics/guidelines-and-policies/post-publication-policies/) for conferences states that the final, published version of a paper cannot appear anywhere online. The author-submitted version, and the accepted version can appear online on preprint servers such as arXiv. You must, however, credit IEEE as the copyright holder for the accepted version.

**Note:** The same policies apply for journals too, as far as I am aware.

Comment: So uploading the author-submitted version(with copy right section), after(!!) it is published in IEEE, is okay?

Comment: I think it should be okay, but I would confirm once with the editor/conference organizers or chairs.